# In PHP, is conditional variable substitution possible?

Tags: php, variables, ternary-operator, substitution

I was wondering if something like the following would be possible in PHP:

```
<?php echo "Hello {isset($name) ? $name : 'World'}!\n"; ?>
```

or do I have to do the following?

```
<?php echo "Hello " . ( isset($name) ? $name : 'World' ) . "!\n"; ?>
```

In general I prefer substitution over concatenation as I find that string concatenation can make strings harder to read by making them overly long.

The context of which is that I'm deciding which option in a select tag should be selected by default based on a database query.

The full context:

```
<?php   
echo "
<form action='add_demographics.php' method='post'>
   <table>
      <input type=hidden name=userId value='{$_SESSION['username']}'/>
      <tr><td>User ID:</td><td>{$_SESSION['username']}</td></tr>";

foreach ($inputLabels as $i => $value)
{
    echo "
      <tr>
         <td>{$value['text']}</td>
         <td><select name=$i>";

    foreach ($value["options"] as $optionName => $optionValue)
    {
    echo "
            <option value=$optionValue {($result[$i]==$optionValue ? ' selected=true' : '')}>$optionValue</option>";
    }
    echo "
          </select></td>
      </tr>";
}

echo "
      <tr><td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' /></td></tr>
   </table>
</form>";
?>
```

Comment: I think what you want to do is not possible within a string, no.

Comment: @Pekka: Dunes is using {} so it will work fine

Comment: @shankhan: Elaborate? The `{}` escapes inside of a string don't, as far as I know, mean you can use any arbitrary expression and have it be evaluated.

Comment: @shankhan are you telling me this is going to work? `{isset($name) ? $name : 'World'}` how?

Comment: @Pekka: Sure it will work. Right after you modify the PHP source tree.

Comment: this will work with little modifications $is_selecte = $result[$i] == $optionValue;
$selected   = 'selected=true';
$unselected = '';{${$is_selecte?'selected':'unselected'}}

Comment: @shankhan: The code you have posted is riddled with syntax errors.

Comment: @webbiedave: because it is not complete; try this { $is_selecte = true;
$selected   = 'selected=true';
$unselected = '';

$string = "hello world {${$is_selecte?'selected':'unselected'}}";
echo $string; }; this should print "hello world selected=true

Comment: @shankhan: Well, this is not what the OP asked for as you are simply using a variable variable in a difficult-to-scan manner, not executing arbitrary code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$default = "World";
$name = "Dunes";
echo "Hello {${isset($name) ? 'name' : 'default'}}";
```

UPDATE from webbiedave:

"Don't ever do this as it's absolutely atrocious coding practice to use the ternary operator to reference a throw away variable variable simply to avoid concatenation!

Comment: Ah, I knew there was a way to do it. I'm new to PHP, but variable subsitituion seemed identical to Bash's implementation. I knew you could do it in Bash, I'd just forgotten how.

Comment: @Dunes, while this does work I'm not sure that its worth the sacrifice you make to readability.  If you have to set the `$default` anyway you might as well do your substitution there and leave your output as `echo "Hello $name";`

Comment: I didn't downvote it but I would definitely reprimand anybody that insisted on submitting this code to me instead of just using concatenation. Your answer should have at least included "Don't ever do this as it's absolutely atrocious coding practice to use the ternary operator to reference a throw away variable variable simply to avoid concatenation!"

Comment: @webbiedave - I did add a notice in the comments that this is not an appropriate way to do things.  I'll update my answer, however, to reinforce that.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - the question was: "I was wondering if something like the following would be possible in PHP."  Well, something like this is possible in PHP.  It being a good idea or not is irrelevant.  Yes, I should have added a note saying that it was *not* a good idea.  But I did answer the question.

Comment: but you know that your answer is ugly. And your logic is ugly as well. It is like a decapitation to relieve a headache. It ANSWERS THE QUESTION too, my ass.

Comment: I added to this to my code just before I left work and I agree that whilst technically it does what I asked, it's not a very pretty way to do things. In part because it requires an extra variable outside the the ternary operator. In the end I used something similar to Alex Vidal's answer.

Answer (score 2):

nope, cannot do that.  You need to do it outside of the string and concat.  The only thing php will do inside a string is look for and evaluate a single $var (no expressions) - if you use double quotes or equivalent heredoc (php does not evaluate vars in single quotes)

Comment: I guess to each his own but...I don't see how putting an expression inside a string is more readable...IMO it should be separate...better yet, give the expression its own line and THEN use the final variable in the echo (inside or outside the string). IOW separate code from content.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't possible to do it the way you're asking.

A solution to your specific problem, however, could be to assign a variable at the top of the foreach loop to hold whether or not that option should be selected, then echo that variable as part of your output:

```
foreach ($value["options"] as $optionName => $optionValue)
{
    $selected = $result[$i] == $optionValue ? "selected='selected'" : "";
    echo "
        <option value=$optionValue $selected>$optionValue</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
    function is($var,$sub){
      return isset($var)?$var:$sub;
    }

    echo 'Hello, '.is($name,'World').'!\r\n';

    $name = 'Bob';

    echo 'Hello, '.is($name,'World').'!\r\n';
?>
```

Maybe for short-handing it?

Answer (score 0):

Given what you want to do. I'd say

```
$string = isset($name) ? $name : 'World';
$result = "Hello $string!\n";
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is never actually required.
Learn to use templates.
HTML should be HTML, not some abstract data hardcoded in PHP

```
<form action='add_demographics.php' method='post'>
   <table>
      <input type=hidden name=userId value='<?=_h($_SESSION['username'])?>'/>
      <tr><td>User ID:</td><td><?=_h($_SESSION['username'])?></td></tr>
<? foreach ($inputLabels as $i => $value): ?>
      <tr>
         <td><?=_h($value['text'])?></td>
         <td><select name="<?=$i?>">
<?   foreach ($value["options"] as $optionName => $optionValue): ?>
            <option value="<?=$optionValue?>" <? if ($result[$i]==$optionValue): ?> selected=true<? endif ?>>
              <?=$optionValue?>
            </option>
<?   endforeach ?>
          </select></td>
      </tr>
<? endforeach ?>
      <tr><td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' /></td></tr>
   </table>
</form>
```